# embed font-awesome icons in a single html

Tags: font-awesome

I need to create a single page html application with all the js and htmls included in the same page. Is there a way where I can include font awesome library and icons in a single html and use it. My page is angular based. I will be getting htmls with fa icons like :

```
<div><i class="fa fa-{{data.icon}} fa-{{styling.iconSize}}" style="color:     {{styling.iconColor}}"></i></div>
```

which I need to convert to something using maybe base64 encoding or SVG format of fa icons.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://fontello.com/ , it is by far the easiest way to do what you are describing and not bloat your single file.

You are able to select only the icons you are actually using, and download a custom zip.

Within the zip, you will find a css file with "embedded" in the name (at least, as of this writing, they do include it). You can copy and paste the contents of that file into your single-file HTML page between  tags.

Otherwise, yes, base64 encode the font files and put them in place of the font URLs inside of the url() definition.
(e.g.: url('data:application/octet-stream;base64,_THE_BASE64_HERE_')

Here is an online file to base64 converter I've used in the past: https://jpillora.com/base64-encoder/

But if you are really into this single page website idea, then I recommend getting comfortable with gulp (or any of the similar build tools), and using something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-base64 which will automatically process your css file, replacing any files referenced in them with base64 encoded inline data. This allows you to keep things separate and then build to a single file.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The "[Getting Started](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/)"-Page lists various possibilies to include the CSS. And if you only need a few icons and blazing performance, you might want to look at their [FortAwesome](https://fortawesome.com/) project which enables you to include a subset of the icons in your page (for a charge...).